# Download a image from web to desktop folder JS

Tags: javascript

Okay, I´m working on something that combines lat/lng and assembles a link that goes :

```
 image = "http://...center={{lat}},{{lng}}&zoom=15&size=500x500"
```

While having only 2 arguments LAT and LNG I "assemble" the link and it turns out to lets say

http://staticmap.openstreetmap.de/staticmap.php?center=14.51233,9&zoom=15&size=500x500

Now this is an image. And I would like to download it to my files(any location). What are easiest solutions to this? JS only.

I've been trying something and I do indeed save a file however not as image. if i force `filename = date + ".jpg"` i get "jpg" but its bugged file and not viable.

```
var saveUrlAsImage = function(image) {
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    var filename = date;
    var path = mydirectory + '/' + filename;
    return fs.writeFileAsync(path)
        .then(function() {
            return image.save();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert("bad");

        });

};
```

In short: What am i missing to save url image as real image? Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: what is your web server? you have to send it to the client.

Comment: You want the right `MIME-Type` sent as `header`.

Comment: Any other workarounds? Or direction on what should I do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do it with JS code, the browser won't allow it. You can create a link/anchor to the file, and then "click" it:

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = "http://staticmap.openstreetmap.de/staticmap.php?center=14.51233,9&zoom=15&size=500x500";
link.target = "_blank";
link.click();
```

But again, the browser will use the user preferences how open the file according to its type. For images it will probably be opened in a new tab, if you try with different file types, it might be downloaded.

Comment: problem is i have like dozen of those, and i want them "automatically" saved. Not by clicking or any user effort. When funct goes off that they are saved. And mine does it but not really as a image.

Comment: When you use the `click()` you simulate a user click, he doesn't have to really click anything. There is no "
magical" way to force a download.

Comment: Yeah but does this actually save the image? Im not sure if i follow. Apologizes. Mind clarifying a bit?

Comment: It depends on the user preferences (which are unlikely to save images, other file types may work) and you CAN'T change it.